# Pure bash: extracting a substring by combining ## and %% in one command?

Tags: bash

Given:

```sh
string="apple banana cherry"
```

How can I extract `banana` using the ## and %% expansions in one command?

My closest attempt is two commands:

```sh
tmp=${string##*apple }
echo ${tmp%% cherry*}
banana
```

Clarification: In my case, banana might be `banana23`, `banana38`, or other numeric suffix.

Comment: What is special about `banana`? If you want to get the second element, maybe do `cut -d' ' -f2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` and `%` can't be combined. You can use regex matching, though

```
[[ $string =~ apple\ (.*)\ cherry ]]
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

or assign to an array and select the second element:

```
fruits=($string)
echo ${fruits[1]}
```

You can also use `set` to populate the positional parameters

```
echo $(set -- $string ; echo $2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`extglob`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob):

```
shopt -s extglob

string="apple banana cherry"
echo "${string//@(apple | cherry)/}"
```

```
banana
```

Here expression `@(apple | cherry)` matches one of the strings separated by `|` inside `(...)`